# Is there no option to turn off cell broadcasting messages in HTC Desire 500?

Tags: cell-broadcast, htc-desire-500

I got the recently launched HTC Desire 500 (Android  4.1.2, Sense 5).

Since then I am continuously getting cell broadcasting messages (4 every 2 minutes). And shockingly, there is no option to turn off the cell broadcast neither in message settings nor in Call settings.

When I compared my HTC Desire X with Desire 500, I saw the option is there in Desire X but not in Desire 500. The call center people are helpless. The Customer care center people are saying its a defect in the phone's software, so we cant repair it.

So by the time the software update comes, does anyone here has any solution. It is really irritating and its sad that HTC doesn't have the solution to such a trivial issue which is actually a headache.

Comment: Have you checked the other 7 [questions tagged cell-broadcast](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell-broadcast)? Maybe any of those solutions apply to your case as well?

Comment: As I learn from [Vodofone's support page](http://forum.vodafone.co.uk/t5/HTC-Desire-series/HTC-Desire-How-to-stop-receiving-texts-from-34-50-34-with-area/td-p/458407/page/2), I understand that this is an issue in the ROM. Either you may have to check whether any software updates are available, or to demote to a lower version or try a custom ROM to solve this issue.

Comment: I purchased this phone, and you are right. Cell broadcasting messages has become the biggest headache for me. I tried to talk to HTC customer care twice. They do not have any working solution. They suggested me to inset the SIM into another mobile and switch off cell broadcasting, but that didn't work for me. I am planning to take HTC to consumer court. It's not a joke. It's a bug in their device of which we are suffering. I travel a lot with my job. Within 90 kms of distance, I generally receive 160 messages. I also can't use Maps because of this bug. It's really annoying.

Comment: One of my colleauges has Desire 500 for month and finally found a solution to disable Cell Broadcast, but unfortunately I do not know how. I can only confirm that it was possible!

Comment: Maybe you could ask him and include those details?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this works as I believe broadcast settings are not stored in SIM. I searched and stumbled on [this](http://www.htcforums.com/other-htc-devices/13063-htc-desire-500-how-tur-off-cell-broadcast-sms.html) HTC support page where the solution is said as:

> I resolve problem. It is very simple. Just put your sim card in old or
>   some other phone and turn off cell broadcast info option. Then return
>   your sim in new phone. On my HTC Desire 500 there is no option for
>   cell broadcast. After this procedure I do not recives messages.

Then, another [search result](http://www.flipkart.com/htc-desire-t327w-x-dual-sim/p/itmdhsk6raeeytcb?) says with better detail (you may have to search for `Cell Broadcast`. Though this not deals with your phone (with HTC Desire T327W), I guess this seems to be a common issue with few HTC phones. As per that page:

> 26-Sep-2013 - My earlier review talks about Cell Broadcast messages
>   problem faced by me while using HTC Desire XDS. After a lot of
>   followup with HTC, I have got the steps using which the Cell Broadcast
>   messages have got disabled in my Desire XDS. The steps taken by me
>   were as follows for each of the two SIM cards:
>   a) Find an old phone which has an option to enable/disable Broadcast Channels and Messages
>   (in my case its a Samsung D500).
>
> b) Insert the first SIM in that old
>   phone and go to the settings menu for Broadcast messages.
>
> c) At first
>   the Channels and Messages usually appear as disabled. I changed the
>   setting for both Channels and Messages to Enabled in the old phone.
>
> d) Switch-off the old phone and Switch-on
>
> e) Go to the settings menu
>   for Broadcast messages. Change the settings for both Channels and
>   Messages to Disabled.
>
> f) Switch-off the old phone and Switch-on
>
> g) Switch-off the old phone and remove SIM card
>
> h) Do the same steps (a-g) for the second SIM
>
> i) Insert the SIM cards back in HTC Desire
>   XDS
>
> Now I do not get any Broadcast Messages, its such a relief. I hope HTC
>   provides a better and elegant solution via a software update in the
>   upgrade to Android 4.3.