# Is there no option to turn off cell broadcasting messages in HTC Desire X dual sim?

Tags: htc, cell-broadcast, htc-desire-x

I searched lot on google but I didn't find any working solution to stop receving messages from "50"

I tried these solution but didn't work for me - [Is there no option to turn off cell broadcasting messages in HTC Desire 500?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54673/is-there-no-option-to-turn-off-cell-broadcasting-messages-in-htc-desire-500)

Does anyone really have a proper solution (have experienced).

Also please dont mark this question as duplicate.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add what version of android your device runs. Some of the settings may be dependant on the version of android.

Comment: Also check [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41545/turning-off-cell-broadcast-messages-in-htc-one-x-plus?rq=1) and see if it helps your issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just remove the SIM from the phone. In the message settings of phone, it will show as disabled.

Restart the phone, and check and uncheck cell broadcast settings. Then insert the SIM in your phone. It worked for my phone, so hopefully it will work for yours as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please open your stock "messaging" app --> go to settings inside messaging app --> scroll down and you should have "cell broadcast settings" option. Click on that and there uncheck the option provided.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Sam there is no  setting option in messaging

Comment: After opening the messaging app please tap ":" (three vertical dots) on right hand top corner of your screen and you should be able to go inside "settings" and then you can turn off the "cell broadcast settings".

Comment: there is setting option but no  cell broadcast

Comment: Setting->call->cell broadcast->uncheck it .. Please try this.

Comment: i chat with HTC Customer Care Executive they repiled me there is no option for cell broadcast in HTC Dual SIM Phone :-(

Comment: If you have any other phone. Please put the same sim card in that phone and go to settings inside messaging app (samsung phone) or Setting->call->cell broadcast->uncheck it (htc phone) to stop getting messages. Somebody else had same problem and they did this to stop it. Please try.

Comment: Hi I came across this video which shows precisely how to turn off cell broadcast settings. Please check this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juLMhR_Ijls

Answer (score 0):

Setting->call->cell broadcast->uncheck it (Surely can stop **Cell info display** in **HTC ONE M8** by this way)

Comment: This will also disable important *cell broadcasts* in case of emergency. Just keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I have an HTC 10 and someone just told me this was happening from me to them.  This is how I fixed it (oddly, no one else told me they get this odd CB# thing). CB is cell broadcasting or in my case, CALLBACK.  Go into your mssging, then the 3 dots (settings), go to GENERAL.  Scroll down to the bottom.  I DIDNT have CELL BROADCAST, I had CALLBACK.
Remove the checkmarks out of Callback Number for SMS and Callback Number for MMS.  This should resolve the issue for YOU sending the callback to someone else. I verified with my person that Im not sending her the callback line anymore.
I cannot find a setting if someone is sending it to you. THEY would need to fix on their own phone.  If you don't know the person texting you, I suggest you BLOCK them.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve it.

Go to `default messaging app` -> goto `Settings` -> select `Cell Broadcast`. Suppose, if everything is off, but you still get messages, then, go to `Customized Channels` and add `channel 50` (the one that serves me annoying messages). It will be enabled default. Click on it again, and set it to disabled to block the channel. That is it.